# O valor da variável não atualiza

Tags: php, php-7

Olá, eu instalei o WAMP da Bitnami e estou usando o php 7.1.7 e quando eu edito o valor de uma variável, e dou F5 no navegador, o valor da variável não muda na página web.

Testei em 3 navegadores, Firefox (o que uso), Chrome e Edge. Estou usando o echo para mostrar o valor da variável, e o valor não altera na mesma hora que atualizo o navegador, tenho que esperar uns 2 a 3 minutos e então atualizo o navegador novamente e então atualiza. Esse procedimento é toda vez que mudo o meu script, estou usando somente 2 linhas, uma para variável e outra para o echo e mais nada.

Alguém sabe como resolver isto? Já usei .htaccess e mudanças no conf do apache e não resolveu.

Comment: Coloca aqui o código que você está tendo problemas.

Comment: <?php $nome = "Bruno"; echo $nome; ?> Somente isto, qualquer coisa que alterar já não atualiza na hora, somente depois de uns minutos no navegador.

Comment: Um pergunta meio óbvia (rs), antes de você apertar F5 pra ver o novo valor da sua variável, você troca o valor da variável `$nome`, certo ?

Comment: HAHAHA essa foi boa, mais troco o valor sim, mesmo quando dar errado eu mudo o valor para ver se muda, e nada.

Comment: sim, mais já resolveu, da uma olhada na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que pode ser problema de Cache, ja ouvi falar disso no apache e no php, não tenho certeza se terá resultado, mas tente configurar o seguinte:

1) Google PageSpeed ​​Module é habilitado nestas linhas em 
{$INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf:

```
 Include conf/pagespeed.conf
 Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

`Comente essas linhas para desativar este módulo.`

2) O PHP possui Op Cache  ativado nas linhas em 
{$INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/etc/php.ini:

```
 opcache.enable=1
 opcache.enable_cli=1
```

`Desative mudando de 1 para 0`

Se não for isso não imagino o que seja.

Comment: Olá, fiz a opção do OPCache e resolveu, estava ativado e desativei. Obrigado

Comment: Que bom q deu certo. ^^ Abraços